# Lambda and SQL queries that changes over time

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to deploy multiple Lambda Functions with each one issuing Athena SQL queries. This query may change depending on schema changes of the table involved.

I'm considering to create a sql file in s3 or to redeploy this s3 lambda function every time the queries change. Is there any recommended approach for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which of the following is more important.

- Speed of modifying SQL statements
- Speed of Lambda function execution

You could have the Lambda function reach out to an S3 bucket to grab a SQL file on every invocation but that would be wildly inefficient and more expensive. You could slightly improve upon this by using a caching strategy to check if the file had changed (by hash/checksum) before pulling it down.

The better approach would be to include the SQL in the function and simply re-deploy when you want to change the SQL. Without, further context I can't say if this will suit your needs (perhaps you need to be able to swap the SQL very quickly.) Deploying Lambda functions can be very quick however if setup properly (<1 minute to update a single function).

There might be a third approach where you parameterize your Lambda function and SQL commands such that you don't need to change the SQL as frequently and simply pass different parameters to the function.